# Signal filtering in Python

Tags: python, plot, filter, signals, wave

Trying to create a filter for a signal i made, but can't seem to get. I keep getting error about '/' whenever i call my filter function.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import sqrt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
import math

def sinyal(N,c,f,p):
    y=np.zeros(N)
    t=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,N)
    Nf=len(c)
    for i in range(Nf):
        y+=c[i]*np.sin(f[i]*t)
    return y;

def filter (w,wn):
    yf=1.0/sqrt(1.0+(w/wn)**(2.0*n))
    return yf;

c=[2,5,10]
f=[50, 150, 300]
p=[0,0]
N=2000
w=[50,150,300]
x=np.linspace(0,2.0*math.pi,N)
y=sinyal(N,c,f,p)

yf=filter(w,200)

plt.plot(x[:100],y[:100])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

- `w` is a list, `wn` is an `int`, so `w/wn` raises

  ```
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
  ```

  You could fix the error by making `w` a NumPy array:

  ```
  w = np.array([50, 150, 300])
  ```
- You'll also need to define `n`.
- `filter` is called but the result is never used.
- Tip: note that `filter` is the name of a [Python builtin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter). It's
  best not to define a function or variable the same name as a builtin,
  since it makes it harder to access the builtin and may be confusing
  to others.
- Tip: Python does not need semicolons at the end of statements.

Comment: When i plot it, do i plot it x,y or x,yf?